# Import local ".py" library in powerbi python scripting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have written a python library *(ak_sql.py)* to query my sql server and written another *".py"* script *(query_sql.py)* to invoke this library and return data in dataframes.

I want to `"import query_sql"` in "Python srcipt" in PowerBI, so i can load those dataframes.

I invoked PowerBi from powershell from the root of "query_sql", like below:

```
C:\Users\akshat\Documents\ak_sql> C:\Users\akshat\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PBIDesktopStore.exe
```

However, PowerBI was unable to find the module.

I tried printing `"os.getcwd()"`, this is the output:

```
C:\Users\akshat\PythonSriptWrapper_{hashkey}
```

Any inputs on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So seems like it was a PYTHONPATH issue. Was a able to take care of it with appending sys.path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\akshat\Documents\ak_sql>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the empty file `__init__.py` in the ak_sql directory and make change in your script on

```
from ak_sql import query_sql
```